# Reading state from the database blue prism

Tags: automation, rpa, blueprism

any one to help ,
I would like to know the status of process ( running, pending...)
Any VBO that can help process that verify the status of different process blue prism

Answer (score 1):

No VBOs that I'm aware of which do this out of the box. The tables BPASession and BPAResource in the database should give you the information you need. There's a "GetSessionId()" function in the calculation stage which gives you the session of the currently running process. Depends on your use case!

Answer (score 0):

These activities are being called as RPA Supervision.

Open CMD, Navigate to Blue prism's automate directory
Start Resource PC listener using command - automate /public /resourcepc
Note this will start Resource PC as public Resource PC Alternatively, you can also run it exclusive to specific user by using /user  
Connect to listener using telnet - telnet localhost 8181 (or to whichever port you have configured)
Type the commands busy/availability as suggested in help reference, to get the status of the said resource PC.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771275%28v%3dws.10%29#to-install-telnet-client-on-windows-7-or-windows-vista

These are the Steps for confirming status of the Resource PC where your Processes are running.

But In Order to get the Status of Different Processes you would require access to DataBase and also use powershell to fetch Data.

Usually Prod DB accesses are restricted ,secured by admins/RPA Help Teams and aren’t easily granted to every other developer.

But Yes its possible.